# Read Json using C#

Tags: c#, json

Anyone knows how to populate this JSON in a dropdown basically the country-id and :

```
data: {
    "1000": {
      "country-id": 1000,
      "name1": {
        "name": "Afghanistan",
      },
    },
    "4000": {
      "country-id": 4000,
      "name1": {
        "name": "Albania",
      }
    }
```

Comment: Try using a popular JSON library, like Json.NET

Comment: You're going to want to edit your question to explain your scenario more.  Is the client a web browser, C# desktop app, or something else?  Are you having trouble creating the JSON, or do you have the JSON and need to understand how to 'use' the data?  If it's a web browser are you already using a framework like MooTools or JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json is broken and many json parser would complain about it.

I'll use [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) for parsing.

```
    string json = @"{data: { ""1000"": { ""country-id"": 1000, ""name1"": { ""name"": ""Afghanistan"", }, }, ""4000"": { ""country-id"": 4000, ""name1"": { ""name"": ""Albania"", } }";

    var countries = ((JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json))["data"]
        .Children()
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Id = (int)x.First()["country-id"],
            Name = (string)x.First()["name1"]["name"],
        })
        .ToList();
```

Comment: What qualifies the JSON as broken? Thank you

Comment: First it is missing a `{` at the beginning, second, it contains `,`s after the last items like `"name": "Afghanistan",` or `},}`

Comment: Does this produce a list that I can loop into?

Comment: @user1238850 of course, `foreach (var country in countries)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(country.Id + " " + country.Name);
            }`

Comment: How would you add in a where clause? Thank you

Comment: @user1238850 **This is the second time you cancel your "accept" thinking you can force me to answer your new questions, but enough. Before asking a question try to make some research and don't be a [HELP VAMPIRE](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you're aquiring the JSON data but like others have suggested, you're best bet is to use a library such as [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) Here are some basic implementations taken directly from documentation:

If you're serializing/deserializing try the documentation [here](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializingJSON.htm)

```
Product product = new Product();

product.Name = "Apple";
product.ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Price = 3.99M;
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };

string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
//{
//  "Name": "Apple",
//  "ExpiryDate": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//  "Price": 3.99,
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small",
//    "Medium",
//    "Large"
//  ]
//}

Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(output);
```

If you're just interested in querying the data directly try [this](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/?topic=html/LINQtoJSON.htm)

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(@"{
  'CPU': 'Intel',
  'Drives': [
    'DVD read/writer',
    '500 gigabyte hard drive'
  ]
}");

string cpu = (string)o["CPU"];
// Intel

string firstDrive = (string)o["Drives"][0];
// DVD read/writer

IList<string> allDrives = o["Drives"].Select(t => (string)t).ToList();
// DVD read/writer
// 500 gigabyte hard drive
```

I'm guessing the latter is what you're really looking for.